# Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not available

Tags: email, model-view-controller, smtp, razorengine, mvcmailer

Thanks for helping me out when I was stuck in doing something at one time or the other.

I posted a question previously about extracting email contacts from an email address; I got help, but the problem is that I need to send email to the extracted emails using the google smtp server(smtp.gmail.com, 587).

When I try to send email, I receive this message
"Error in processing. The server response was: Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not available"

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and just solved it yesterday. For us it happened when we configured some CName on our zone records. immediately we removed the CNAme records all started going well. Hope it helps