# ASP.NET - Error sending email Messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, gmail, system.net.mail

I checked other questions, and i was able to resolve some errors in my code, but  `smtp.Credentials = nc;` , where nc is my Network credentials, is throwing an exception, **Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not available**.

Please, any help would be appreciated. Below, is my code :

```
           MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("fromemail");
            msg.To.Add("toemail");
            msg.Subject = "Contact Us";
            msg.Body = cname.Text + "sent me this message" + cmessage.Text + "with this email, " + email.Text;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();
            nc.UserName = "fromemail";
            nc.Password = "fromemailpwd";
            smtp.Credentials = nc;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(msg);
            sPanel.Visible = true;
            lblSuccess.Text = "Success! Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you soon.";
```

I changed the `smtp.Credentials = nc` to `smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("fromemail", "fromemailpwd");`
Now, it is this line, `smtp.Send(msg)`, that is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the same error message that you saw, but check out this answer : [Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985321/request-action-aborted-on-mfe-proxy-smtp-server-is-not-available)

However, I do know that Gmail requires EnableSSL = True

Comment: Thanks, i changed the email address, after checking the link, now it says operation has timed out, even though i increased the **smtp.timeout**.